# SPRING BOOT annotation: are they required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Are `@Component`, `@Service` and `@Repository` optional in Spring Boot 2?

Example If have a controller class called FirstController annotated with `@Controller`, `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping`. I also have service classes called FirstService and SecondService and a repository called FirstRespository.

I didn't annotate any of the class except FirstController but still my application works.

Does this mean that those stereotype annotations are not required for your app to make it work? You just need it for convention and if you need to modify behaviour like scope etc.

Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: "I didn't annotate any of the class except FirstController but still my application works.". So you can `@Autowire` a service without it being annotated with `@Service` or `@Component`?

Comment: no annotation at all. so no `@Autowire` also

Comment: So you're not actually using Spring correctly then.

Comment: How are you using FirstService and SecondService in the controller ? Can you show some code ?

Comment: If there is an `@Bean` method creating an instance you don't need an `@Service` or friends. Also both `@Controller` and `@RestController` on a single class don't make sense use either not both. The repositories, when using Spring Data, don't need an `@Repository` annotation to be detected as Spring Data has different ways of detecting repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not required in order for your application to work BUT they will not be picked up by Spring on your application launch nor you will have benefits of that annotation specification

@Component - generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component

@Repository - stereotype for the persistence layer

@Service - stereotype for service layer

Any code can pass when you write your Spring application, but annotation helps Spring to understand what should be created as a bean or a component and for which use.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I was surprise that it works without annotation. All my dependency are injected properly to the dependent class without stereotype annotations and `@Autowired` (but I have defined constructor in each class that accept all the it’s injectable dependencies.) I just Annotate my Controller class and it seems it figure how to manage all the dependency and possible managed beans. I am using Spring Boot 2 and from my memory `@Component` and `@Autowired` are really need except if you define you own spring-context xml.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

private IComponent component;

@Autowired
    public MyService(IComponent component) {
        this.preparingService = preparingService;
    }
}
```

In order to autowire a class implementing `IComponent`, you need to have that class decorated with `@Service` or `@Component` in order for Spring to inject it into `MyService` when `MyService` is itself of course injected in your controller.